Fix for sluggish Bluetooth audio on MacBook M2 with multiple connected devices
What is the fix to the sluggish Bluetooth audio when 3 or more devices are connected to a Macbook with an M2 chip? It is not uncommon these days to have multiple Bluetooth devices, e.g.

Mouse
Keyboard
Pen Tablet
Bluetooth Speaker
Headphone

To name a few.
And according to this post Bluetooth audio is choppy / stuttering the issue with laggy audio is because of multiple devices connected.
The temporary solution to disconnect devices is not possible if you want to type and use a mouse while listening to audio. There must be some fix, e.g. a homebrew fix for this.

You can try resetting the Bluetooth module with sudo pkill bluetoothd. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254533016?answerId=260414984022&sortBy=rank#260414984022

I've done this, however the effect was just temporary.
